# Simulate Enter and send input in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a really simple project to send messages automatically in a website.

I tired the simple: get the input value and then simulate a Enter in the document or try subimit. it doesn't work tho. Could you help me guys?

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
  var field = document.getElementById('chat_textbox');
  field.value = "te";
  //const ev = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13});
  //document.body.dispatchEvent(ev);
  //field.submit();
},4000);
```

And the inspector shows:

input type="text" id="chat_textbox" placeholder="Press enter to chat" maxlength="200">

Comment: `document.body.dispatchEvent(ev);` that will send the event to the `body`, and you most likely want it inside another element.

Comment: I tried field.dispatechEvent(ev)